# how to smoothen dynamic textfield without embedding fonts?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

is there any way to smoothen or make a dynamic textfield look better without embedding fonts? I've tried writing the textfield into a bitmap but haven't been successful with that yet, is there any other better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Flash has to be able to render the font, and to do that it needs to have font data embedded.  You could try just using a default _sans or _serif font that will use the system default.

Comment: yeah i think the best way is still to embed but the problem is that would raise the file size of my SWF and would restrict the use of other fonts